# What does the "has" keyword mean before "method" in a Raku class definition?

Tags: syntax, raku

Recently I realised that I had written, entirely by mistake, one of my Raku classes like this:

```
class Foo {
  has method bar {
    return 'some string';
  }
}
```

I was surprised to realise that the `has method` was not an error, and worked as expected.

What is the `has` doing in this case? Is this an intentional behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`has` is a scope declarator, in the same category as things like `my`, `our`, `state`, and `anon`. Something that is `has`-scoped is installed in the meta-class of the current package.

Variable-like things are always declared with an explicit scope, for example:

```
my $lexical-var;
my $.lexical-var-with-accessor;
has $!attribute;
has $.attribute-with-accessor;
```

Many other constructs can *optionally* have their scope specified, but come with a sensible default. For example:

- `my sub marine() { }` - the same as without the `my`
- `our class Struggle { }` - the same as without the `our`
- `has method in-the-madness() { }` - the same as without the `has`

The most common alternative scope for methods is probably `anon`, which is useful when meta-programming. For example, if we are writing a class that is going to construct another class using the MOP, we may write:

```
$the-class.^add_method('name', anon method name() { $name });
```

Which means we don't end up with the method `name` being installed on the current class we're in. Most of the time, however, we want `has` scope. It does no harm to specify it explicitly, just as it does no harm to write `my` before `sub`; it's just reaffirming a default.